# Two seemingly equal strings not equal

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement, equals

I have a section of code that changes the value of a parameter based on the desired input and output that has been chosen. So in the below example, I calculate the volume of a sphere then depending on the units the user used for the input and the units the user chose for the output the number is manipulated accordingly.

My problem is that all my if statements are returning false and the number 10 (from the else) is coming through regardless of what is chosen. I have printed out the value of inputPref and outputPref and they look exactly equal to "mm" and "cubic cm" (for example) and yet still won't be captured by the if statements.

Any obvious errors? The two variables "inputPref" and "outputPref" are loaded from shared preferences if that helps!

```
double volumeBase = 4 * piDouble * radius * radius * radius / 3;

                double volume;
                if(inputPref.equals("mm") || outputPref.equals("cubic cm"))
                {
                    volume = volumeBase / 1000;
                }
                if(inputPref.equals("mm") || outputPref.equals("cubic metres"))
                {
                    volume = volumeBase / 1000000000;
                }
                if(inputPref.equals("cm") || outputPref.equals("cubic mm"))
                {
                    volume = volumeBase * 1000;
                }
                if(inputPref.equals("cm") || outputPref.equals("cubic metres"))
                {
                    volume = volumeBase / 1000000;
                }
                if(inputPref.equals("metres") || outputPref.equals("cubic mm"))
                {
                    volume = volumeBase * 1000000000;
                }
                if(inputPref.equals("metres") || outputPref.equals("cubic cm"))
                {
                    volume = volumeBase * 1000000;
                }
                else
                {
                    volume = 10;
                }
```

Comment: try inputPref.trim().equals()

Comment: Have you trimmed (`String.trim()`) the strings?

Comment: Also, I have a feeling that your `||` ors should be `&&` ands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your `if` statements (except the first one) should be `else if` statements, so that it only chooses 1 out of all your options.

As it stands, your code may be evaluating an `if` statement early on, but it is getting overwritten by the last `if-else` at the very end, which is almost always going to return `10`.

As pointed out in the comments, you're probably also meaning to use `&&` instead of `||` so that you're running the code when *both* conditions match in each `if` or `else if` statement. You might also consider using `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()`, so that the case of the users input doesn't matter.

It should be...

```
double volumeBase = 4 * piDouble * radius * radius * radius / 3;

double volume;
if(inputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("mm") && outputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cubic cm")){
    volume = volumeBase / 1000;
}
else if(inputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("mm") && outputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cubic metres")){
    volume = volumeBase / 1000000000;
}
else if(inputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cm") && outputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cubic mm")){
    volume = volumeBase * 1000;
}
else if(inputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cm") && outputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cubic metres")){
    volume = volumeBase / 1000000;
}
else if(inputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("metres") && outputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cubic mm")){
    volume = volumeBase * 1000000000;
}
else if(inputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("metres") && outputPref.equalsIgnoreCase("cubic cm")){
    volume = volumeBase * 1000000;
}
else {
    volume = 10;
}
```

If it still isn't working, it might be a problem with the code where you're reading the user input.

Comment: Thanks @SJuan76 good noticing - I think you're probably right based on his requirements. Answer updated as such.

Answer (score 6):

Your `else` at the end will set the volume to `10` if the `inputPref` isn't `metres` or `cubic cm` because only your **last** `if` is related to that `else`. If you put `else` prior to each of the previous `if`s, it may work more as you expect. You also have some duplicates (you're checking for `mm` more than once).

E.g. (but see also below):

```
double volume;
if(inputPref.equals("mm") || outputPref.equals("cubic cm"))
{
    volume = volumeBase / 1000;
}
// v--- Note the `else`
else if(inputPref.equals("mm") || outputPref.equals("cubic metres"))
{
    volume = volumeBase / 1000000000;
}
// ...
```

Also, as [noted by Lews Therin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13453471/157247), I suspect you want `&&` for each pair of those, e.g.:

```
// here -------------------vv
if (inputPref.equals("mm") && outputPref.equals("cubic cm"))
```

not

```
if (inputPref.equals("mm") || outputPref.equals("cubic cm"))
```

Comment: @ppeterka: And it wasn't valid for this use case anyway (just removed it), I'd missed that there are two different variables being checked. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use `else if`'s and in your conditions use && not ||

Comment: Mmn.. not sure why I'm getting downvoted. I think it makes sense if the conditions use && and not ||

Answer (score 1):

probably your last **if** is **failing**, thus **volume** is assigned **10** in the **else**, **Note:** else would only apply for the last if.
use else-if instead of all the if's

```
if(cond){

}
else if(cond){

}
else{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would throw away the Strings, and used enums for this kind of code...

```
public enum LengthUnit {
  M,
  CM,
  MM
}

public enum VolumeUnit {
  M3,
  CM3,
  MM3
}
```

You could even put the conversion rates in there among the similar units, like in [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)

Pros:

- no mistypes, no mysteries
- quicker

Cons:

- requires some efforts to maintain if it needs to be expanded.